# loop through selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the checkboxes which pertains on the same class ,I'm using this function (not finished) tho loop and set a string

```
function estados() {
    var query = "trucades.estat in(";
    var checks = $('.estate_check:checked');

    if (checks.length === 0) {
        query = "not selected ";
    } else {
        //set the message  here ...but only loops once
    }

    return query;
}
```

But checks only contains an object which contains the selected checkboxes but if I try to llop ,it only loops once ,because only contains this object

Comment: There is no loop in your code.

Comment: `checks = $('.estate_check:checked');` will check the length of all the checked check-boxes of class `estate_check`. So it will work one time. Also you don't have any loop in your code

Comment: *loop and set a string* set a string to **what**?

Comment: How do you loop? Do you loop with "each" like that? https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ckbox = $('.my-checkbox:checked');

var str = "";
ckbox.each(function(){
    str += $(this).attr('data-text') + ", ";
});
alert(str);
```

> This fiddle helps you figure it out:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/fx7su2rp/1106/)

Comment: I think we have the same code but I'm using jquery 1.12,and it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to create *query*, You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with `.get()` to create an array of selected values. then [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) can be used to create comma separated string.

```
function estados() {
    var query = "trucades.estat in(";
    var checks = $('.estate_check:checked');

    if (checks.length === 0) {
        query = "not selected ";
    } else {

        //Create an array of selected value
        var selectedValue = checks.map(function () {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

        query += selectedValue.join(',') + ')'
    }

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function estados() {
var query = "trucades.estat in(";
    $('.estate_check:checked').each(function( index ) {
        const val = $( this ).val()
        console.log(index + ': ' + val);
        query += val;
    });
    query += ')';
    return query;
}
```